# Deflate string to PDF throws error invalid code lengths set Java?

Tags: java, pdf, base64, zlib, deflate

I know this question is been asked much time,But i have a deflate string which is of type PDF here it is when i run the following code i am getting this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at dummy.ZlibCompression.shovelInToOut(ZlibCompression.java:66)
at dummy.ZlibCompression.decompressFile(ZlibCompression.java:53)
at dummy.ZlibCompression.main(ZlibCompression.java:78)
```

Here is my code...

```
 public static void compressFile(File raw, File compressed)
    throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(raw);
    OutputStream out =
        new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(compressed));
    shovelInToOut(in, out);
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

/**
 * Decompresses a zlib compressed file.
 */
public static void decompressFile(InputStream compressed, File raw)
    throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(compressed.available());
    InputStream in =
        new InflaterInputStream(compressed, 
                new Inflater(true));
    System.out.println(in.available());
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(raw);
    shovelInToOut(in, out);
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

/**
 * Shovels all data from an input stream to an output stream.
 */
private static void shovelInToOut(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
    int len;
    while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}


/**
 * Main method to test it all.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
   // File compressed = new File("book1out.dfl");
   // compressFile(new File("book1"), compressed); //StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    decompressFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), new File("F:\\decompressed.pdf"));
}
```

When i do sysout i see System.out.println(compressed.available()); size 133844
And System.out.println(in.available()); is 1 (I dont know why)

Here i the deflate string [Temp file link](https://expirebox.com/download/af89846a5b0ae01d66a3a20f0498a4b3.html)

Comment: What is exampleString? How could you even have compressed binary data stored as a String? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply the data is there in XML file,so I am reading as string to test the code, I copied from XML...I am not sure that does it corrupt the data or what..a help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JBNizet BTW its a base64 deflate data from XML

Comment: If it's base64-encoded, then you need to base64-decode it before uncompressing it.

Comment: @JBNizet I did try base64 Decode then Decompressing the file THAT Gives ME A BLANK 194KB PDF file :( In another code

Comment: It's very hard to know how you're supposed to read a file if you don't know how it has been generated.

Comment: @JBNizet this is what i see in XML representation="B64" mediaType="application/pdf" compression="DF"

Comment: I don't know which XML you're talking about. How was the file you're trying to decode and uncompress generated? Precisely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149923/discussion-between-goodyzain-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: I couldn't find a download button for anything but spam I  your linked page https://expirebox.com/download/af89846a5b0ae01d66a3a20f0498a4b3.html .